# Having problems with SQL Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Table **A**

[image]

Table **B**

[image]

I tried to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it seems not working..

[image]

I want the query to extract all data from Table A with 0 as average score if there is no data yet for the specified parameter. Meaning, in Figure 3, it should have shown ID 2 with 0 on s. Can anyone help me figure out the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the table names switched in the join.  To keep all of Table A then it needs to be the table listed on the left side of the left join. Also anything that you want to only affect the output of table B, and not filter the entire results, should be moved to the left join `on` clause. Should be:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       Avg(Isnull(b.score, 0)) AS s 
FROM   a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
                     ON a.id = b.id 
                        AND b.kind = 'X' 
GROUP  BY a.id
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. The solution works well and thank you for explaining why my query is not working.